How can I change or set Android Studio's Background Wallpaper?
I want to set a wallpaper on my Android Studio Software. How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance

If I'm getting you correctly, it's called "background image" and this is how it's done in IntelliJ IDEA (which Android Studio is based on). Check for the same in Android Studio -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/setting-background-image.html

Yes, you are right !!! It's what i want.

That "wallpaper" functionality is actually called "background image" and this is how it's done in IntelliJ IDEA (which Android Studio is based on). Check for the same in Android Studio.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/setting-background-image.html

Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance
Use Background Image button and select the desired image

Alternatively, if the image is in your project, right-click it in the editor or in the Project tool window and select Set Background Image from the context menu.


I got it already , but thank you for explaining!!!

In such a case -- mark the answer as Accepted.
